# Unity - return value to calling coroutine

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a blackjack game in Unity. I have a coroutine called *InitialDeal()* which handles the flow when a player clicks a BET button. It should fetch a random number from the backend API and display the dealing of the cards one by one.

Because fetching data from the API must use *UnityWebRequest* because the game is browser based, it is done in another coroutine called *UnityApiCall*.

So basically I start coroutine A (*InitialDeal()*) in which I start coroutine B (*UnityWebRequest*), and I need that every time I get the response from API, I stop the coroutine A for a number of seconds while the card is dealt.

This is what I tried. This is coroutine B that calls my API:

```
    private IEnumerator UnityApiCall(String method, String path, String pathParams, String body, Action<JObject> result)
        {
    
            Debug.Log("In UnityApiCall...");
    
            using UnityWebRequest www = new UnityWebRequest(apiUrl + path);
            www.method = method;
            if(www.method == "POST") {
                byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body);
                UploadHandlerRaw uH = new UploadHandlerRaw(byteArray);
                www.uploadHandler = uH;
            }
            
            www.downloadHandler = new DownloadHandlerBuffer();
    
            www.SetRequestHeader("Session-ID", sessionId);
    
            yield return www.SendWebRequest();
    
            if (www.result == UnityWebRequest.Result.ConnectionError)
            {
                Debug.Log(www.error);
                if (result != null)
                    result(new JObject("{error: " + www.error + "}"));
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log(www.method + " successful!");
    
                String str = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(www.downloadHandler.data);
    
                JObject jsonResponse = JObject.Parse(str);
                
                if (result != null)
                    result(jsonResponse);
            }
        }
```

This is the coroutine A:

```
private IEnumerator InitialDeal()
    {
        // initial deal
        ChangeGameState(GameState.OnDealing);

        int betAmount = (int) ChipManager._Instance.stacks[(int) StackType.Standard].GetValue();
        Debug.Log("Bet value: " + betAmount);
        // int betAmount = 10;
        BetRequest betRequest = new BetRequest();
        betRequest.amount = betAmount;
        string pathParams = "";
        string body = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(betRequest);

        yield return UnityApiCall("POST", "/bet", pathParams, body, (JObject response) =>
        {
            Debug.Log("response: ");
            Debug.Log(response);

            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                // CardData cardData = new CardData(CardData.Suit.Hearts, CardData.Rank.Four);
                // CardData cardData2 = new CardData(CardData.Suit.Spades, CardData.Rank.Five);

                var playerNum = response["data"]["playerCards"]["0"]["cards"][i]["number"];
                var playerSymbol = response["data"]["playerCards"]["0"]["cards"][i]["symbol"]["symbol"];

                var dealerNum = response["data"]["dealerCards"][i]["number"];
                var dealerSymbol = response["data"]["dealerCards"][i]["symbol"]["symbol"];

                var playerCard = MapCard(playerNum.ToObject<int>(), playerSymbol.ToObject<string>());
                var dealerCard = MapCard(dealerNum.ToObject<int>(), dealerSymbol.ToObject<string>());

                DealQueue.DealCard(player.DealCard(playerCard));
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(DEAL_WAIT_TIME);

                if (i == 0)
                {
                    DealQueue.DealCard(dealer.DealCard(dealerCard, FlipType.FlipDown));    
                }
                else
                {
                    DealQueue.DealCard(dealer.DealCard(dealerCard, FlipType.FlipUp));   
                }
            
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(DEAL_WAIT_TIME);
            }
            ChangeGameState(GameState.OnPlay);
        });
        

        
    }
```

This is how I tried to stop the execution for a few seconds (in the callback of UnityApiCall in the snippet above):

```
yield return new WaitForSeconds(DEAL_WAIT_TIME);
```

However, this doesn't work since it's in the callback function, and I cannot use yield there.

This is how I called the coroutine A:

```
StartCoroutine(InitialDeal());
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right in the way you wait for the UnityApiCall. The callback does get the JObject but it is only local to the callback. Instead, assign it to another JObject that is method scope:

```
JObject jObject = null;
yield return UnityApiCall("POST", "/bet", pathParams, body, 
    (response) => jObject = response);
// You can use the jObject
Debug.Log("Response " + jObject );
// Your code here processing jObject
// You are in the coroutine so you can yield all you need
yield return new WaitForSeconds(DEAL_WAIT_TIME);
ChangeGameState(GameState.OnPlay);
```